# How to share data of tableViewCell to next viewController without using storyboard in ios with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, tableview, segue

I am using Xib files in my project for building interface of my app.
I have a tableView in my first viewController from which I want to pass data to next ViewController. I have created a custom cell for my tableView which contains an imageView and two labels.

This is my code

```
import UIKit

class YASProductListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // registering my custom cell
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "YASProductListTableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    let cell : YASProductListTableViewCell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! YASProductListTableViewCell
    cell.productNameLabel.text = prodcutNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.productDetailLabel.text = productDetail[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return prodcutNames.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 140
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YASProductListTableViewCell

    let destination = YASProductDetaiilViewController(nibName: "YASProductDetaiilViewController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

    destination.productImage = cell.productImageView.image
    destination.productTitle = cell.productNameLabel.text!

    let productDetails = YASProductDetaiilViewController(nibName: "YASProductDetaiilViewController", bundle: nil) as YASProductDetaiilViewController
    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    navigationController?.title = ""
    navigationController?.pushViewController(productDetails, animated: true)

}
```

Now what I want to do is pass the image and labels text to next viewController when user tap on any cell. Here is the code of next ViewController

```
import UIKit

class YASProductDetaiilViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var productImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var productTitleLabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupViewControllerUI()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

// MARK: - UIViewController helper Methods

func setupViewControllerUI(){

    productImageView.image = productImage
    productTitleLabel.text = productTitle
}
}
```

As you can see I have tried it didSelectRowAtIndexPath but its not working. Please help! Thanks

Comment: are you using uinavigation controller?

Comment: shall you change the weak property to strong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using right method to share data between viewController. However you have made a mistake. You are creating two instance of your ProductDetailViewController. You need to create only one instance of destination ViewCotroller and then set its properties accordingly you you can simply replace your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method with following

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YASProductListTableViewCell
    let productDetails = YASProductDetaiilViewController(nibName: "YASProductDetaiilViewController", bundle: nil) as YASProductDetaiilViewController
    productDetails.productImage = cell.productImageView.image
    productDetails.productTitle = cell.productNameLabel.text!
    navigationController?.pushViewController(productDetails, animated: true)

}
```

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Change your didSelect method like below code,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YASProductListTableViewCell

let productDetails = YASProductDetaiilViewController(nibName: "YASProductDetaiilViewController", bundle: nil) as YASProductDetaiilViewController
navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
navigationController?.title = ""
productDetails.productImage = cell.productImageView.image
productDetails.productTitle = cell.productNameLabel.text!
navigationController?.pushViewController(productDetails, animated: true)

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yeah that sounds great...!!

Comment: Not getting you...First you accept my answer and now you deselect it. why?

Comment: I upvoted your answer dear. Because the new accepted answer is explaining the actuall issue as well.

Comment: You can't up vote bcz as you don't have enough reputation right now and by  the way if you ask me for your issue then i will explain you. Its ok.

Answer (score 0):

Do as follow might be help you.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YASProductListTableViewCell
        let objYASProductDetaiilViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("STRORYBOARD_ID") as? YASProductDetaiilViewController     
        objYASProductDetaiilViewController.productImage = cell.productImageView.image
        objYASProductDetaiilViewController.productTitle = cell.productNameLabel.text!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objMedicalDevicesVC!, animated: true)
        navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
        navigationController?.title = ""
        navigationController?.pushViewController(objYASProductDetaiilViewController, animated: true)

    }
```

Here You can not assign a `image View` to `image View` directly.You need to get a image first then it give to a other view controller image then set it to image to `UIImage`

```
    import UIKit

    class YASProductDetaiilViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var productImageView: UIImage!
    @IBOutlet weak var productTitleLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViewControllerUI()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    // MARK: - UIViewController helper Methods

    func setupViewControllerUI(){

        productImageView.image = productImage
        productTitleLabel.text = productTitle
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**create dictionary of all the needed information and the add to array and get using indexpath.row when cell is clicked**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

var dicTemp=prodcutNames[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary
let destination = YASProductDetaiilViewController(nibName: "YASProductDetaiilViewController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

destination.productImage = prodcutNames.valueForKey("imageObj") //get image object
destination.productTitle = prodcutNames.valueForKey("product_title")//get product title

let productDetails = YASProductDetaiilViewController(nibName: "YASProductDetaiilViewController", bundle: nil) as YASProductDetaiilViewController
navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
navigationController?.title = ""
navigationController?.pushViewController(productDetails, animated: true)

}
```